# MySQL aggregate function to filter nulls and conform with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have a single record which joins to *N* other tables, and extracts a single column from each of them.  I would like to put all *N* of those extracted columns in a single record.

After constructing the diagram below it seems like I can get to the second step easily, and then I should be able to use an aggregate function to filter out the `NULL`'s.  I have looked around for something like `GROUP_COALESCE`, but I couldn't find something which accomplishes this.

I have a fiddle here which unfortunately works, because MySQL will let you select columns which aren't in the `GROUP BY` without an aggregate at your own peril http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/304992/1/0.

Is there a way I can make sure that it always selects the column from the record, if the record exists?

The end result should one record per group, and each column would contain the value which was inside the only row successfully joined for that group..

[image: Intuitively I think this should work]

Comment: Please, consider to edit your question and share us what is your code problem, what are expected results and what you already tried

Comment: What is your expected result for the sample data in the fiddle?

Comment: @forpas The fiddle output is correct, but as I understand it it is grabbing an arbitrary value since the column it is grabbing is not included in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: If you only want results that have matches on all 3 tables, why not use `INNER JOIN`? Aggregation really should not be needed here unless you have multiple matches from a tableN to the same group_record.

Comment: The row being left joined may not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you can just use aggregate functions on the columns coming from the joined tables. Aggregate functions ignore null values, so, since you have two null values and one non-null value for each column and each group, this will return the expected output (while conforming to the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY option).

```
SELECT 
    group_table_id, 
    MAX(t1.v) t1_v,
    MAX(t2.v) t2_v,
    MAX(t3.v) t3_v
FROM group_table
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.group_id = group_table_id
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.group_id = group_table_id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.group_id = group_table_id
GROUP BY group_table_id
```

Comment: Won't `t1_v` still be null If there are no matches in t1, or all matched t1 entries have NULL `v` values?